# Find percentage in MySQL (Reviews >= 3 out of 5 / Total reviews)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains customer UUID and customer rating out of 5. For each UUID, I need to find percentage of neutral + positive reviews (reviews with rating >= 3) vs total reviews of that customer UUID. Can anyone please help me with the SQL query?

[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output according to that sample data, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

So I used pre-aggregation and solved my problem step by step:

First I selected all rows in my sample space ie customers who have added reviews in the last 3 months:

```
with all_surveys_with_rating as (
    select
    uuid,
    rating
    from table
    where date_diff('month', from_unixtime(context.server_timestamp / 1000), now()) <= 3
    and uuid <> ''
    and survey_status = 'SURVEY_TAKEN'
    and rating is not null
)
```

pre-aggregation is similar to defining variables in code

Now I need 2 types of data from this

1. Total count of a customers' reviews = total
2. Total count of positive+neutral ie rating > 7 reviews of a customer = p + n

total:

```
all_surveys_count as (
    select uuid, COUNT(uuid) as count
    from all_surveys_with_rating
    group by uuid
)
```

p + n

```
positive_or_neutral_surveys_count as (
    select uuid, COUNT(uuid) as count
    from all_surveys_with_rating
    where rating >= 7
    group by uuid
)
```

Now I need to do ***for a uuid ->  p+n / total * 100***

So I need to join p+n and total table. Now it has to be LEFT JOIN as a customer may have no positive reviews, that way his uuid doesn't exist in p+n table:

```
select all_surveys_count.uuid, cast(coalesce(positive_or_neutral_surveys_count.count, 0)  * 100 as decimal (12,2)) / all_surveys_count.count
from all_surveys_count
LEFT JOIN positive_or_neutral_surveys_count
ON all_surveys_count.uuid = positive_or_neutral_surveys_count.uuid
```

I used coalesce to handle the case of 0 p+n reviews of a customer since uuid will be null in that case. I casted p+n count to decimal for the division to give a decimal number.

Final query:

```
with all_surveys_with_rating as (
    select
    uuid,
    rating
    from table
    where date_diff('month', from_unixtime(context.server_timestamp / 1000), now()) <= 3
    and uuid <> ''
    and survey_status = 'SURVEY_TAKEN'
    and rating is not null
), all_surveys_count as (
    select uuid, COUNT(uuid) as count
    from all_surveys_with_rating
    group by uuid
), positive_or_neutral_surveys_count as (
    select uuid, COUNT(uuid) as count
    from all_surveys_with_rating
    where rating >= 7
    group by uuid
) 
select all_surveys_count.uuid, cast(coalesce(positive_or_neutral_surveys_count.count, 0)  * 100 as decimal (12,2)) / all_surveys_count.count
from all_surveys_count
LEFT JOIN positive_or_neutral_surveys_count
ON all_surveys_count.uuid = positive_or_neutral_surveys_count.uuid
```